# How can I use same Mongo DB with Python & NodeJS app concurrently?

Tags: python, node.js, mongodb

I created a Python (Django) app, connected it to MongoDB & inserted some data with python app. Now I created a NodeJS app and connected it to same MongoDB, connection was successful, however, when I am running queries to fetch data from DB using NodeJS app, I am not getting any data or any error.

Is this a problem with some version or compatibility within MongoDB, Python & NodeJS? How can I use same Mongo Database with NodeJS & Python app concurrently?

Comment: Can you kindly share your code so we can try to see where the issue is?

Comment: Just for clarity, yes you can connect with multiple apps of any language using compatible drivers for the mongodb version you are using. You MAY need to adjust [connection pools](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/administration/connection-pool-overview/), but in your context of having two servers connecting, I wouldn't've thoughts so.